# How to join a multi-index series to a single index dataframe with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, multi-index

Consider the following single index DataFrame:

```
      energy    fat
1      2000      28
2      1900      17
3      2200      30
4      1750      15
5      1800      18
6      1600      12
```

I also have a multindex Series:

```
1  vitamin-c    0.0004
   vitamin-a    0.0150
2  vitamin-c    0.0030
3  vitamin-d    1.2000
   vitamin-e    1.0007
   vitamin-c    1.2020
4  vitamin-a    0.0780
5  vitamin-b    0.9650
6  vitamin-e    1.9801
   vitamin-c    1.0011
```

How can I join the two so the result looks like this:

```
      energy    fat          vitamins
1      2000      28     vitamin-c    0.0004
                        vitamin-a    0.0150
2      1900      17     vitamin-c    0.0030
3      2200      30     vitamin-d    1.2000
                        vitamin-e    1.0007
                        vitamin-c    1.2020
4      1750      15     vitamin-a    0.0780
5      1800      18     vitamin-b    0.9650
6      1600      12     vitamin-e    1.9801
                        vitamin-c    1.0011
```

I tried `df.join(series, how = 'inner')` but all I got is the following error message:

```
"ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names"
```

Can someone please explain me what im doing wrong here and how i can achieve the combination of the two ? Thank you !

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example? Code to generate your `Series` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
I don't suggest moving things into the index that shouldn't be there.
That said, you can use `pd.DataFrame.join` if your index levels are appropriately named, or rather they match so pandas knows what to join on.

```
df.rename_axis('ord').join(s.rename_axis(['ord', 'vit']).rename('val'))

               energy  fat     val
ord vit                           
1   vitamin-c    2000   28  0.0004
    vitamin-a    2000   28  0.0150
2   vitamin-c    1900   17  0.0030
3   vitamin-d    2200   30  1.2000
    vitamin-e    2200   30  1.0007
    vitamin-c    2200   30  1.2020
4   vitamin-a    1750   15  0.0780
5   vitamin-b    1800   18  0.9650
6   vitamin-e    1600   12  1.9801
    vitamin-c    1600   12  1.0011
```

---

In a couple more lines to add readability

```
s = s.rename_axis(['ord', 'vit']).rename('val')
df = df.rename_axis('ord')

df.join(s)

               energy  fat     val
ord vit                           
1   vitamin-c    2000   28  0.0004
    vitamin-a    2000   28  0.0150
2   vitamin-c    1900   17  0.0030
3   vitamin-d    2200   30  1.2000
    vitamin-e    2200   30  1.0007
    vitamin-c    2200   30  1.2020
4   vitamin-a    1750   15  0.0780
5   vitamin-b    1800   18  0.9650
6   vitamin-e    1600   12  1.9801
    vitamin-c    1600   12  1.0011
```

---

**Option 2**
We can also use `pd.concat` with `loc` and `pd.Index.get_level_values`

```
pd.concat(
    [df.loc[s.index.get_level_values(0)].set_index(s.index), s.rename('val')],
    axis=1
)

             energy  fat     val
1 vitamin-c    2000   28  0.0004
  vitamin-a    2000   28  0.0150
2 vitamin-c    1900   17  0.0030
3 vitamin-d    2200   30  1.2000
  vitamin-e    2200   30  1.0007
  vitamin-c    2200   30  1.2020
4 vitamin-a    1750   15  0.0780
5 vitamin-b    1800   18  0.9650
6 vitamin-e    1600   12  1.9801
  vitamin-c    1600   12  1.0011
```

Comment: this is very smart !

Comment: rename_axis is nice way to do it!

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for your answers and @piRSquared for your comprehensive explanation. Is 'rename_axis()' any better than 'index.names = ()' ? (solution suggested by Andy Hayden)

Comment: @solub it serves the same purpose.  The difference is that using `rename_axis` allows you to rename the index levels "inline".  This facilitates some pipelining exercises, writing code with fewer lines of code, readability... point is that it is a subjective call and entirely up to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you add names to the index/multiindex you can use a join:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   energy  fat
n
1    2000   28
2    1900   17
3    2200   30
4    1750   15
5    1800   18
6    1600   12

In [12]: df2
Out[12]:
                val
n vitamin
1 vitamin-c  0.0004
  vitamin-a  0.0150
2 vitamin-c  0.0030
3 vitamin-d  1.2000
  vitamin-e  1.0007
  vitamin-c  1.2020
4 vitamin-a  0.0780
5 vitamin-b  0.9650
6 vitamin-e  1.9801
  vitamin-c  1.0011

In [13]: df.join(df2)
Out[13]:
             energy  fat     val
n vitamin
1 vitamin-c    2000   28  0.0004
  vitamin-a    2000   28  0.0150
2 vitamin-c    1900   17  0.0030
3 vitamin-d    2200   30  1.2000
  vitamin-e    2200   30  1.0007
  vitamin-c    2200   30  1.2020
4 vitamin-a    1750   15  0.0780
5 vitamin-b    1800   18  0.9650
6 vitamin-e    1600   12  1.9801
  vitamin-c    1600   12  1.0011
```

Note: Do this by setting the .index.names:

```
In [21]: df.index.names = ["n"]  # or .name = "n"

In [22]: df2.index.names = ["n", "vitamin"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Source  sets:

```
In [96]: s
Out[96]:
id   vitamins
1.0  vitamin-c    0.0004
     vitamin-a    0.0150
2.0  vitamin-c    0.0030
3.0  vitamin-d    1.2000
     vitamin-e    1.0007
     vitamin-c    1.2020
4.0  vitamin-a    0.0780
5.0  vitamin-b    0.9650
6.0  vitamin-e    1.9801
     vitamin-c    1.0011
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
   energy  fat
1    2000   28
2    1900   17
3    2200   30
4    1750   15
5    1800   18
6    1600   12
```

Solution:

```
In [99]: s.reset_index() \
          .merge(df, left_on='id', right_index=True) \
          .set_index(['id','energy','fat','vitamins'])
Out[99]:
                             val
id  energy fat vitamins
1.0 2000   28  vitamin-c  0.0004
               vitamin-a  0.0150
2.0 1900   17  vitamin-c  0.0030
3.0 2200   30  vitamin-d  1.2000
               vitamin-e  1.0007
               vitamin-c  1.2020
4.0 1750   15  vitamin-a  0.0780
5.0 1800   18  vitamin-b  0.9650
6.0 1600   12  vitamin-e  1.9801
               vitamin-c  1.0011
```