# Joining a single-index dataframe to a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, structured something like

```
# df1
                        data1   data2
id      feature_count   
12345   1               111     888
        2               222     999
        3               333     101010
45678   0               444     111111
        2               555     121212
        3               666     131313
        4               777     141414
```

and

```
# df2
        descriptor
id
12345   "foo"
45678   "bar"
```

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47145286) it seems like I should simply be able to do `df1.join(df2)` to get the desired result

```
#joined
                        data1   data2   descriptor
id      feature_count   
12345   1               111     888     "foo"
        2               222     999     "foo"
        3               333     101010  "foo"
45678   0               444     111111  "bar"
        2               555     121212  "bar"
        3               666     131313  "bar"
        4               777     141414  "bar"
```

However, what I actually get is `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented` in Pandas 1.0.5.

This seems like it shouldn't be complicated, but I'm clearly misunderstanding something. All I'm looking for is to append the column of unique mappings in `df2` on to the (guaranteed existing mapping) first index of `df1`.

Comment: I can't duplicate your error. I have version 1.0.5 too. Your example code works for me. Does your example code work for you or do you get the error on the larger dataset?

Comment: It was a much larger dataset pulled in from a SQL query. After I accepted the answer (and a different error proved to be more informative) I think that the query had unexpected duplication  (which I'm surprised Pandas let me assign an index to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to map one column, just do:

```
df1['descriptor'] = df1.index.get_level_values('id').map(df2['descriptor'])
```

In general, you can temporarily reset the other index, join the dataframes, and set it back:

```
df1.reset_index('feature_count').join(df2).set_index('feature_count', append=True)
```

Output:

```
                     data1   data2 descriptor
id    feature_count                          
12345 1                111     888      "foo"
      2                222     999      "foo"
      3                333  101010      "foo"
45678 0                444  111111      "bar"
      2                555  121212      "bar"
      3                666  131313      "bar"
      4                777  141414      "bar"
```

Comment: Your first case still gave me an error, but your second worked like a charm. Thanks!