# Using a multi index in a dataframe to join to a single index

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.  However, I'm trying to create a multi-index off three fields, which eventually will be three separate joins based upon input data.

I'm creating a second data frame in the example below, which I want to use a date lookup table, which will be able to join to the expiration date.

When I try to create the multi-index I get the following error:

ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.

I've tried turn the dataframe data_index into a series, but I'm still getting the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from datetime import date

raw_data = requests.get(f"https://cdn.cboe.com/api/global/delayed_quotes/options/_SPX.json")
dict_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data.json())
#create dataframe from options key
data = pd.DataFrame(dict_data.loc["options", "data"])
# regex to strip the contract type, strike, and expire date
data["contract_type"] = data.option.str.extract(r"\d([A-Z])\d")
data["strike_price"] = data.option.str.extract(r"\d[A-Z](\d+)\d\d\d").astype(int)
data["expiration_date"] = str(20) + data.option.str.extract(r"[A-Z](\d+)").astype(str)
# Convert expiration to datetime format
data["expiration_date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["expiration_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

data_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(data, names=[["expiration_date", "strike_price", "contract_type"]])  ## this is where the error occurs
print(data_index)

date_df = pd.DataFrame(data[["expiration_date"]].unique())
date_df.set_index('expiration_date').join(data_index.set_index('expiration_date')) 
today_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
days_till_expire = (np.busday_count(today_date,date_df["expiration_date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_list())/ 252)
date_df.loc[date_df["days_till_expire"].eq(0), "days_till_expire"] = 1 / 252
print(date_df)
```

How can I get the multi index to work with a join on a single index?  Joining the date_df into the multi_index dataframe?  I believe the logic below should work if the multi-index is setup correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too long to put it into comments, so here in form of an answer:

I suppose that what you wanted to achieve is this (not from the entire frame, but from the three columns out of it):

```
data_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([data["expiration_date"], data["strike_price"], data["contract_type"]], names=["expiration_date", "strike_price", "contract_type"])  ## this is where the error occurs
```

For how to join on a single index check out:
[How to join a multi-index series to a single index dataframe with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144979/how-to-join-a-multi-index-series-to-a-single-index-dataframe-with-pandas#47145274)

Does it help you?

Comment: It helps, but why wouldn’t from data frame work?

Comment: From dataframe all of the columns would become part of the MulltiIndex but you have provided only three of the column names and not all of them (may be not true - haven't tested it, but suppose it was the reason for the error message).

Comment: Ok, I do want all of the columns that are part of data to be in data_index.  But, I only want those three as the index for a quicker join to the reference tables i'll be creating.  So, wouldn't dataframe be what I want?  That makes sense that I'd have to include all in name.  Instead of typing each one is there an easier way to include all?

Comment: *So, wouldn't dataframe be what I want?* Sorry, I was not able to see the main idea and its purpose from the code. You are the one to know what you want, isn't it? Maybe you explain in detail in the question what you actually want to achieve to get better response? I am not fluent in Pandas ... I mean to have read in pandas docu that if you don't give any names all columns will be taken, but ... what it still remains unclear for me what is it all good for?